# how to initialize private members of class in c++

Tags: c++, std-pair

Hi i have a c++ class with some private members as follows

```
    template <typename V, typename E>
    class Vertex
    {
     public:
      Vertex();
      ~Vertex();
      typedef std::pair<int, E> edgVertPair;
      typedef std::vector<edgeVertPair> vectEdges;
      void setVertexID(int data);
      int getVertexID();
      void setEdgeVertPair(int vertID, E edge);
      edgVertPair getEdgeVertPair();    
      void setEdgeList(edgeVertPair edgeVert);
      vectEdges getEdgeList();
    private:
      int vertexID;
      edgVertPair evp;
      vectEdges edgeList;  
    };
```

Now i want to create a pair i.e. something like

`evp.first="someint";
evp.second="somestring";`

and then push this evp into the edgeList i.e. edgeList.push_back(evp);
Now the problem is in the setter function i did something like this:

```
    template<typename V, typename E>
    void Vertex<V, E>::setEdgeVertPair(int vertID, E edge){
            ...populate evp;...
    }
```

now i don't know how to populate the evp pair with vertID, edge.

Comment: Ignoring the reason you're storing the values in `evp` and then adding them to the vector, doesn't `evp = make_pair(vertID, edge); edgeList.push_back(evp);` work ?

Comment: Nothing to do with visual studio. untagged.

Comment: You have asked 15 questions and none have been answered?

Comment: thanks zabba, but the thing is that the edgelist will most of the times contain this pair but there may be times when i just need to create a pair and not store it in a vertex. anyways the other thing is that my intellisense doesn't work i.e. when i do something like 'evp.' then it is supposed to show the properties like first or second, but it doesn't so that's why i asked about initializing this pair.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to all who replied to my question, i figured it out after some search. one way was i removed the typedef's and in my private data section, declared the variables directly as

```
std::pair<int, E> evp;
std::vector<std::pair<int, E>> edgeList;
```

and that worked fine.

the other way was i had to prepend the keyword 'typename' before typedef's and it worked.

Comment: -1: Removing the typedefs may help intellisense but you shouldn't be writing code to work around its limitations. It's there to assist you when you write code, not teach you how to write code.

Answer (score 2):

Use `std::make_pair` to populate the evp pair.

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/std/utility/make_pair/

Comment: Thanks for the link, but i am facing a different issue as i have a templatised class and don't know if simply using evp.first or evp.second will populate the pair as the intellisense says "No members ..." so i am confused.